# Mysql Disallow insert on certain table and time everyday

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables **member** and **points** in `mysql`.

Everyday at **21.00 pm**, I run a script to calculate member **points** which will be updated in `points` table and needs to stop insert query in table points until tomorrow morning 8.00 am.

**Questions:**

- What are the best approach to handle disallow insert query on table "points"?

Comment: Just Get the current time and check if it is in between the time you want to disallow and put the insert statement as per the condition

Comment: Do you want the queries to "points" to be discarded or saved?
You can create a temporary table temp_points, change your script to save all queries to "temp_points" after 21:00 pm up to 8:00 am and then merge the tables each morning (add temp_points data to points). Or just "block" the queries in the script,in the required time frame, if you don't care about discarding them.

Comment: Use a stored procedure to do the insert query. You can put logic in a stored procedure to either check the time, or check a global flag or table-based flag to see if it's ok to do the insert.

Comment: Look at table locks https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: Thanks for all the help. ill try all the suggestions and tell the results later on

Comment: i decided to go with Event Scheduler to grant and revoke insert to certain user in mysql.